# CSS borders and padding not all the same

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
        <!-- start setup section -->
            <div class='photo-setup'>

                <div class='setup-head'>
                    <div class='photo-name'>Photo Name : <input type='text' placeholder='Photo Name' name='photo-name' title='Photo Name'></div>
                    <div class='photo-date'>Photo Date : <?php echo date('F j, o', time()) ?></div>
                </div>

                <div class='photo-section'>
                    <img src='' width='600' height='600' alt='photo'>
                </div>

                <div class='tag-section'>
                    Tags :  <input type='text' placeholder='Tags e.g. (#beach #park #dog)'>
                </div>

                <div class='commit-section'>
                    <a class='save' href='#'>Save</a><a class='cancel' href='#'>Cancel</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        <!-- end setup section-->
```

CSS:

```
img { border: none; }

.photo-setup {
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.setup-head {
    border-left: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-right: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-top: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    padding: 1em;
}

.photo-name { float: left; }
.photo-date { float: right; }


.photo-section {
    border-left: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-right: 1px solid #cacece;
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/rw5beqtk/

Question 1: Why is the top and bottom padding in `setup-head` not the same?

Question 2: Why is the border of `photo-section` not the same as `setup-head`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions 1:

You have a `float left` and `float right` on `photo-name` and `photo-date` as such taken out of the normal flow, you have to add `overflow:auto` to the parent class so it does not lose its padding state.

```css
img { border: none; }

.photo-setup {
 width: 600px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.setup-head {
 border-left: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-right: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-top: 1px solid #cacece;
 border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: auto;
}

.photo-name { float: left; }
.photo-date { float: right; }


.photo-section {
 border-left: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-right: 1px solid #cacece;
}
```

```html
<!-- start setup section -->
<div class='photo-setup'>
    <div class='setup-head'>
        <div class='photo-name'>Photo Name : <input type='text' placeholder='Photo Name' name='photo-name' title='Photo Name'></div>
        <div class='photo-date'>Photo Date : <?php echo date('F j, o', time()) ?></div>
    </div>

            <div class='photo-section'>
                <img src='' width='600' height='600' alt='photo'>
            </div>

            <div class='tag-section'>
                Tags :  <input type='text' placeholder='Tags e.g. (#beach #park #dog)'>
            </div>

            <div class='commit-section'>
                <a class='save' href='#'>Save</a><a class='cancel' href='#'>Cancel</a>
            </div>

        </div>
<!-- end setup section-->
```

Question 2: It is the img childs border which the browser adds to it if there is not a `src` for it and can not be overridden. Easy fix for you though is to remove (as you already have a border round the image)

```
.photo-section {
    border-left: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-right: 1px solid #cacece;
}
```

from your code

```css
img { border: none; }

.photo-setup {
 width: 600px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.setup-head {
 border-left: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-right: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-top: 1px solid #cacece;
 border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: auto;
}

.photo-name { float: left; }
.photo-date { float: right; }
```

```html
<!-- start setup section -->
<div class='photo-setup'>
    <div class='setup-head'>
        <div class='photo-name'>Photo Name : <input type='text' placeholder='Photo Name' name='photo-name' title='Photo Name'></div>
        <div class='photo-date'>Photo Date : <?php echo date('F j, o', time()) ?></div>
    </div>

            <div class='photo-section'>
                <img src='' width='600' height='600' alt='photo'>
            </div>

            <div class='tag-section'>
                Tags :  <input type='text' placeholder='Tags e.g. (#beach #park #dog)'>
            </div>

            <div class='commit-section'>
                <a class='save' href='#'>Save</a><a class='cancel' href='#'>Cancel</a>
            </div>

        </div>
<!-- end setup section-->
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: @RobertRocha Are you aware of when adding a valid image `src`, there will be no more border? ... The now visible image border shouldn't be taken into account as it is only there because the image is missing

Comment: @LGSon yes i am aware

Comment: @RobertRocha Okay, and I though it was obvious to address the missing border on the `photo section` element, which I didn't add, as it was unclear whether the border top/bottom of it should be the image itself, but now I did update it with how it should be applied.

Comment: Glad it helped @RobertRocha

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: Why is the top and bottom padding in setup-head not the
>   same?

Because your child element is floated and as such taken out of the normal flow. Setting `overflow:hidden` on `setup-head` will fix that.

```
.setup-head {
    border-left: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-right: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-top: 1px solid #cacece;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

> Question 2: Why is the border of photo-section not the same as
>   setup-head?

It is the `photo-section`'s `img` child's border, so you get double. When an `img` element doesn't have a valid `src`, it gets a border representing the image size, which won't go away with `border: none`.

---

Sample snippet with an image and `overflow: hidden`

```css
img { 
  border: none;
  vertical-align: top; 
}

.photo-setup {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.setup-head {
  border-left: 1px solid #cacece;
  border-right: 1px solid #cacece;
  border-top: 1px solid #cacece;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photo-name { float: left; }
.photo-date { float: right; }

.photo-section {
  border: 1px solid #cacece;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='photo-setup'>

  <div class='setup-head'>
    <div class='photo-name'>Photo Name : <input type='text' placeholder='Photo Name' name='photo-name' title='Photo Name'></div>
    <div class='photo-date'>Photo Date : <?php echo date('F j, o', time()) ?></div>
  </div>

  <div class='photo-section'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/600/eee' width='600' height='600' alt='photo'>
  </div>

  <div class='tag-section'>
    Tags :  <input type='text' placeholder='Tags e.g. (#beach #park #dog)'>
  </div>

  <div class='commit-section'>
    <a class='save' href='#'>Save</a><a class='cancel' href='#'>Cancel</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add overflow: hidden; to .setup-head or [clear your floats](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).
2. They are the same. You see a 2px border because the image is missing.